# Derivative of sum of Gaussians wrt. sigma - How does this work?

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution, differential

Let $\varepsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$ be samples from independent Gaussians, we know by additivity of independent Gaussians that $\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon'$ where $\varepsilon' \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)$.

We can also write this with $\varepsilon^*_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ as

$\sigma_1 \varepsilon^*_1 + \sigma_2 \varepsilon^*_2 = \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}\varepsilon^*_3$

What confuses me here if that while both terms describe the same distribution, their derivatives with respect to $\sigma$ are quite different.

$\frac{d}{d\sigma_1} \sigma_1 \varepsilon^*_1 + \sigma_2 \varepsilon^*_2 = \varepsilon^*_1$

whereas

$\frac{d}{d\sigma_1} \sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}\varepsilon^*_3 = \frac{\varepsilon^*_3\sigma_1}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}}$

So I see something is going wrong here, I suspect this is because using standard differential calculus might not extend to cases where random variables are involved(?). Can someone here clarify for me, why these derivatives differ and what the right tools for computing derivatives involving random variables would be?
Also feel free to correct my notation, I'm not a mathematician.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that while the random variables $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ do not depend on the choice of $\sigma_1$ as they are assumed to just be independent variables both distributed by $\mathcal N(0,1)$, the random variable $\varepsilon_3$ *does* depend on the choice of $\sigma_1$. Yes, its distribution is $\mathcal N(0,1)$, but it is not just another independent random variable but defined in terms of $\varepsilon_1$, $\varepsilon_2$, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. You would need to take $\frac{\mathrm d\varepsilon_3^*}{\mathrm d\sigma_1}$ into account.

Comment: Oh! this is interesting! Could you give me an idea, what $\frac{d\varepsilon_3^*}{d\sigma_1}$ would look like? I don't really have an idea, how to approach this.

Comment: Well, by definition $e_3^* = \frac{\sigma_1 \varepsilon_1^* + \sigma_2 \varepsilon_2^*}{\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}}$, now you can just take the derivative with respect to $\sigma_1$.

Comment: I see... that's of course trivial. So I guess my takeaway here is that $\varepsilon_3^*$ is a function of $\varepsilon_1^*$ and $\varepsilon_2^*$ which happens to be Gaussian itself, but this shouldn't obscure the dependence. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: “We know by basic additivity of Gaussians...” this specific fact only holds for *independent* Gaussians, which is not explicitly mentioned here, by the way. Otherwise, a correlation term appears in the variance of the sum of the RVs.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 The form with a correlation term is also a special case where the RVs are *bivariate* normally distributed. In general, the sum of two normal random variables need not even be normal.

Comment: Good point! I've updated the question to clarify.